# Accessing Swash Glyphs in Minion Pro Italic

Tags: fontspec, minionpro

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
 fontspec: {\fontspec{MinionPro-It} Qa He}
 
 text swash: {\fontspec[RawFeature=+cswh]{MinionPro-It} Qa He}
\end{document}
```

which with xelatex produces the following:

[image]

However, with lualatex the two lines are identical.  I suspect the issue is that the swash glyphs in Minion Pro are accessed contextually and lualatex is interpreting the substitution rules differently.  To this end I am wondering how one can access the glyphs?  Opening up the font in fontforge one can see there is a swash substitution table in `gsub` although as it does not have a standard name it does not appear to be accessible via fontspec.

**Edit**

I found a copy of TexLive 2019 on this machine.  Running this through it works perfectly with both `lualatex` and `xelatex`.  I am therefore reasonably confident that there has been a regression in behavior between TL2019 and TL2021.

Comment: With an up-to-date TeX Live, I can’t reproduce the problem.

Comment: My version is 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021). For testing I am using MinionPro-It.otf from Adobe Reader with MD5 (MinionPro-It.otf) = 45e2315e99f24ab596f9d3aed29a0fc3 (the version I own is older and so wanted to eliminate it as a variable).

Comment: Which version of `fontspec`?

Comment: It claims to be `{2020/02/21}{2.7i}{Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX}`